# How instead of Numeric display string as '-' in a CASE statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, null, case

I have a simple CASE statement where in my ELSE block numeric column I want to display as '-'.
But it gives me an error

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

How would I do that?
I want it like this:
[image]

```
SELECT 
            CASE WHEN ChargeName = 'Premium' THEN CompanyCommissionPercentage  ELSE '-'  END AS CompanyCommissionPercentage
             ,CASE WHEN ChargeName = 'Premium' THEN RemitterCommissionPercentage ELSE '-'  END AS RemitterCommissionPercentage
             ,CASE WHEN ChargeName = 'Premium' THEN RemitterCommission ELSE '-'END AS RemitterCommission
             ,CASE WHEN ChargeName = 'Premium' THEN GrossCommission ELSE '-'END AS GrossCommission
FROM @tmpAccountsPayable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
`SELECT 
            CASE WHEN ChargeName = 'Premium' THEN CAST(CompanyCommissionPercentage as varchar(10))  ELSE CAST('-' as varchar(10))  END AS CompanyCommissionPercentage

FROM @tmpAccountsPayable`
```

Comment: Yep.  a result set can only have one data type for a column.  Since the first value encountered is numeric, then the column is set to numeric. The system then tries to implicitly cast the - to a numeric and fails, thus the error.  So casting the numeric to varchar data type would resolve the issue as you've seen.  Note: you don't need to cast the '-' to varchar(10) it's already character data.

Comment: Didnt know about this simple thing. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Glad to help, and glad you were able to figure out what to do.  All I did was offer the why.  I find knowing why helps!  Also note: In Excel you could pass in 0 instead of - and have Excel treat zeros in formatting as a dash.  I believe it's called an accounting style (or select `,` from the toolbar under home menu-->number

Comment: Oh, thats good to know. Cause im not great in Excel. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here's a picture of where in excel you can set formatting to a `-`

You may be better off passing in a zero instead of the dash and allowing excel formatting to make the 0 a - (assuming of course the output is going into excel)

Notice below in E20 the 0 value is converted to a - when accounting format (comma format) is used.

Also notice how a regular dash is left aligned while the accounting - is indented.

[image]